# Horizontal size class of popovers in Catalyst?

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst, uitraitcollection, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

If I present a view controller as a popover on iPad (by setting its `modalPresentationStyle` to `.popover`), it will report its horizontal size class as `.compact`. But if I run the same code in a Catalyst app, the view controller in the popover reports a horizontal size class of `.regular`. Compact is what I expect. Setting [`overrideTraitCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipresentationcontroller/1618335-overridetraitcollection) on the `popoverPresentationController` of the view controller before I present it works to make the size class regular on iPad, but it won't make it compact on Catalyst.

How can I make a view controller in a popover correctly report a compact horizontal size class in Catalyst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked an Apple engineer this in a WWDC 2021 lab on Catalyst and he said it's a bug. I've filed it as Feedback FB9124431.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @VictorEngel Nope. Still broken in Monterey 12.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the Catalyst authors set the default to `.regular` on Macs since popovers can be a lot bigger in general.

If you want to override it just on Macs I’d use an `#ifdef`, eg:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
// set ‘overrideTraitCollection’ so it forces '.compact’ on the popover
#endif
```

Comment: `overrideTraitCollection` on the popover presentation controller doesn't do anything on Catalyst, sadly.